# RighNow ProductCategoryInput Widget change the selected value

Tags: oracle, rightnow-crm

In Oracle customer portal (rightNow) I want to to change the selected value of the ProductCategoryInput widget dynamically which is already setup with attribute name="Incident.Products".

for example,if I had two radio buttons:

1. Employee.
2. Student.

So, if you clicked on employee, the ProductCategoryInput widget selected value changed to Information Technology.

and, if you clicked on student, the ProductCategoryInput widget selected value changed to Education affairs.

to sum up, I want ProductCategoryInput dropdown list value to be triggered dynamically using JS

Answer (score 1):

If the subscribed events of the default widget don't work for your use case, which it sounds like they don't, then you can extend the default code with your own custom code (i.e. a custom widget) to create an event subscription that will update the value when triggered.  This is a common practice to update and extend the capabilities of the default widgets.  You can use the [Customer Portal public documentation](http://documentation.custhelp.com/euf/assets/devdocs/cloud20d/olh/CustomerPortal/topicrefs/c_Extending_an_existing_widget_bw1132134.html) and the widget documentation in Customer Portal administration to explore the default functionality and plan for any updates that you might need in order to achieve your desired functionality.

Comment: thanks Scott I appreciate your support I will give it a try